# AnalyticsReporting V4: Can I combine a DynamicSegment and a segmentId as logical AND?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to migrate a few queries from Core Reporting V3 to V4 (AnalyticsReporting V4 in PHP to be specific). In one case I'd like to combine a custom segment with one of the "predefined" segments.

**Expected result:**

I receive a response where BOTH segments are applied to the response (logical AND)

**Actual result:**

I receive a response where each row is listed individually for each segment.

**My question**

How do I apply BOTH segments to receive ONE row per result? In this case - get all users that came via Tablet or Desktop and have had more than three sessions.

In V3 I did this by combining multiple user::condition:somethingSomething.

I guess one way would be to first get the segment definition of the predefined segment that I need, and then use it to build a SegmentDimensionFilter - but it would be nice to avoid that.

**Here is my (test) query**, with segmentId: 'gaid::-15' being "Tablet and Desktop Traffic". In my real query I'm using a SequenceSegment, but the response is the same here:

```
+"dateRanges": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#542 ▼
      +"endDate": "2016-05-18"
      +"startDate": "2016-04-18"
    }
  ]
  +"dimensions": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#545 ▼
      +"name": "ga:segment"
    }
  ]
  +"metrics": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#546 ▼
      +"expression": "ga:users"
    }
  ]
  +"segments": array:2 [▼
    0 => {#548 ▼
      +"dynamicSegment": {#549 ▼
        +"name": "AK: Loyal Visitors"
        +"userSegment": {#553 ▼
          +"segmentFilters": array:1 [▼
            0 => {#556 ▼
              +"simpleSegment": {#560 ▼
                +"orFiltersForSegment": {#563 ▼
                  +"segmentFilterClauses": array:1 [▼
                    0 => {#566 ▼
                      +"dimensionFilter": {#570 ▼
                        +"dimensionName": "ga:sessionCount"
                        +"expressions": "3"
                        +"operator": "NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    1 => {#543 ▼
      +"segmentId": "gaid::-15"
    }
  ]
  +"orderBys": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#547 ▼
      +"fieldName": "ga:users"
      +"sortOrder": "DESCENDING"
    }
  ]
```

**And here is the response**, notice how each segment is listed individually as its own dimension:

```
"columnHeader" => array:2 [▼
  "dimensions" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "ga:segment"
  ]
  "metricHeader" => array:1 [▼
    "metricHeaderEntries" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "name" => "ga:users"
        "type" => "INTEGER"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
"data" => array:6 [▼
  "rows" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "dimensions" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "Tablet and Desktop Traffic"
      ]
      "metrics" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "values" => array:1 [▼
            0 => "74309"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "dimensions" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "AK: Loyal Visitors"
      ]
      "metrics" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "values" => array:1 [▼
            0 => "10740"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "totals" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "values" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "85049"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "rowCount" => 2
```

Would appreciate any help on this! Please let me know if I should clarify something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multiple Segments

As your query results prove an Analytics Reporting API V4 ReportRequest can have multiple segments, and each segment shows up in the `ga:segment` dimension in the results.

### Logical AND segment filters

To answer your question No you cannot **OR/AND** together a segment id with your own clauses, because a given segment Id can be composed up of several individual filter clauses.

In fact the segment Id you requested has two segmentFilterClauses:

```
gaid::-5 == sessions::condition::ga:deviceCategory==tablet,ga:deviceCategory==desktop
```

### But all is not lost

As you surmised you will need to create your own set of segment Filters:

```
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:segment"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:users"
        }
      ],
      "segments": 
      [
        {
          "dynamicSegment": 
          {
            "userSegment": 
            {
              "segmentFilters": 
              [
                {
                  "simpleSegment": 
                  {
                    "orFiltersForSegment": 
                    [
                      {
                        "segmentFilterClauses": 
                        [
                          {
                            "dimensionFilter": 
                            {
                              "dimensionName": "ga:sessionCount",
                              "operator": "NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN",
                              "expressions": 
                              ["3"
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "simpleSegment": 
                  {
                    "orFiltersForSegment": 
                    [
                      {
                        "segmentFilterClauses": 
                        [
                          {
                            "dimensionFilter": 
                            {
                              "dimensionName": "ga:deviceCategory",
                              "expressions": 
                              ["tablet","desktop"
                              ],
                              "operator": "IN_LIST"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "name": "AK: Loyal mobile users"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Checkout the above example in the API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/analyticsreporting.reports.batchget/m/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet?_h=5&resource=%257B%250A++%2522reportRequests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522viewId%2522%253A+%25221234%2522%252C%250A++++++%2522dimensions%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Asegment%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522metrics%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522expression%2522%253A+%2522ga%253Ausers%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522segments%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522dynamicSegment%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++%2522userSegment%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++%2522segmentFilters%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++%255B%250A++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++%2522simpleSegment%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++%2522orFiltersForSegment%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++%255B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522segmentFilterClauses%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++%255B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522dimensionFilter%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522dimensionName%2522%253A+%2522ga%253AsessionCount%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522operator%2522%253A+%2522NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522expressions%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%255B%25223%2522%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%255D%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++%255D%250A++++++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++++++%255D%250A++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++%2522simpleSegment%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++%2522orFiltersForSegment%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++%255B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522segmentFilterClauses%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++%255B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522dimensionFilter%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522dimensionName%2522%253A+%2522ga%253AdeviceCategory%2522%252C%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522expressions%2522%253A+%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%255B%2522tablet%2522%252C%2522desktop%2522%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%2522operator%2522%253A+%2522IN_LIST%2522%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++++++++++%255D%250A++++++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++++++%255D%250A++++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++++++++%255D%250A++++++++++++%257D%252C%250A++++++++++++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522AK%253A+Loyal+mobile+users%2522%250A++++++++++%257D%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&)

### Segment Id is backwards compatible

On top of being able to logically *AND* or *OR* segment Filters, the [Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) is backwards compatible with the [V3 segment syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments):

```
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:segment"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:users"
        }
      ],
      "segments": 
      [
        {
          "segmentId": "users::condition::ga:deviceCategory==tablet,ga:deviceCategory==desktop,ga:sessionCount>3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Matt, you just saved me ten hours worth of banging my head against the wall, trying everything I could think of. THANK YOU! I'll probably end up using the V3 syntax in this case. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is error in the line

```
"users::condition::ga:deviceCategory==tablet,ga:deviceCategory==desktop,ga:sessionCount>3"
```

Instead ",", we must write ";"

```
"users::condition::ga:deviceCategory==tablet,ga:deviceCategory==desktop;ga:sessionCount>3"
                                                                       ^
```